# Allow linking books written in foreign languages (and not distributed on Amazon.com) from Careers profiles

Tags: feature-request, jobs, amazon

It seems you are only referencing amazon.com in [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). The book I wrote is in German and only to be found via amazon.de; even the ISBN is not found.

Can you please change the handling accordingly?